# Intel Graphics Installer "Error removing old repository configuration"

Tags: 14.04, drivers, intel-graphics

I am running the Intel Graphics Installer on my 14.04 system, but it fails to install drivers. I get past the first step with:

```
Checking if Intel graphics card available... OK
Retrieving information from 01.org... OK
Checking distribution... OK
Checking kernel version... OK
Checking available repositories... OK
Checking package manager status... OK
```

but clicking install gives me "Error removing old repository configuration:". My graphics card info looks as follows:

```
: ~ $ sudo lshw -C video 
   * -display 
        description: VGA compatible controller 
        product: 82G33 / G31 Express Integrated Graphics Controller 
        manufacturer: Intel Corporation 
        physical id: 2 
        bus info: pci @ 0000: 00: 02.0 
        version: 10 
        width: 32 bits 
        clock: 33MHz 
        capabilities: msi pm vga_controller bus_master cap_list rum 
        configuration: driver = i915 latency = 0 
        resources: irq: 44 memory: fe980000-fe9fffff ioport: cc00 (size = 8) memory: d0000000-dfffffff memory: fe800000-fe8fffff
```

I am also trying to run Glmark2, but it gives med the following error:

```
~$ glmark2
Error: Glmark2 needs OpenGL(ES) version >= 2.0 to run (but version string is: '1.4 Mesa 10.4.0-devel')!
Error: main: Could not initialize canvas
```

Is my graphics card (integrated) outdated or is there some other explanation. I tried putting in some other PCI graphics cards, but removed them as the Glmark2 score was sub par and I didn't see any noticable difference compared to the built-in Intel card. Below glxinfo for the built-in card:

```
$ glxinfo | grep -i opengl
OpenGL vendor string: Intel Open Source Technology Center
OpenGL renderer string: Mesa DRI Intel(R) G33 
OpenGL version string: 1.4 Mesa 10.4.0-devel
OpenGL extensions:
```

Any suggestions?

Thanks!

Comment: Ubuntu 14.04 is not supported by Intel Graphics Installer. It can not be installed. This question is outdated.

Answer (score 0):

The error regarding the removal of the old repository was in my related to pkexec which was not found (don't ask how it dissapeared).

I downloaded and installed policykit-1 package :

```
wget http://launchpadlibrarian.net/150623542/policykit-1_0.105-3ubuntu3_amd64.deb
sudo dpkg -i policykit-1_0.105-3ubuntu3_amd64.deb
```

You should adapt with the package that belongs to your distribution version